PrimeNG V18 Virtual Scroller with Angular 18 @if syntax
I have been using @for to loop through my dataset and display the same structure of elements over and over, but the dataset has grown quite large so I've been trying to implement the VirtualScroller component since I'm using PrimeNG.
The component wouldn't render and would just be blank on the inside and I couldn't figure out why. I finally starting going line by line and adding things in 1 a time and it seems to break on a line where I was using the @if syntax. No errors or anything.
I've recreated the issue here in stackblitz and it seems to be an issue with the virtualscroller component of PrimeNG, but I wanted to ask the community in case perhaps I'm not supposed to be using that syntax inside of a template or maybe I'm using it wrong.
Hopefully someone has an idea!
Here is a snippet of the code also:
<div class="card flex justify-center">
  <p-virtualscroller
    [items]="items"
    [itemSize]="50"
    scrollHeight="200px"
    styleClass="border border-surface"
    [style]="{ width: '200px', height: '200px' }"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item let-options="options">
      <div
        class="flex items-center p-2"
        [ngClass]="{ 'bg-surface-100 dark:bg-surface-700': options.odd }"
        style="height: 50px"
      >
        @if(truthy) { {{ item }} }
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-virtualscroller>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'panel-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './panel-basic-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule],
})
export class PanelBasicDemo {
  selectedPreset: string = 'aura';

  items!: string[];

  truthy: boolean = true

  constructor(private config: PrimeNGConfig) {
    this.config.theme.set({ preset: Aura });

    this.items = Array.from({ length: 1000 }).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);
  }
}


To my knowledge this is my analysis:
The properties of the component are not visible inside the ng-template since it is rendered inside primeng virtual scroll, instead attach the variable to the data array, hence it will be accessible.
But this is a bug in primeng, mostly due to change detection, this happens for @if and *ngIf. Please raise a bug on their github. You should also mention that the virtual scroll documentation api page is not showing properly.

Error: .localservice@runtime.d3acb9e1.js:26 ERROR RuntimeError: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: 'undefined'. Expression location: Scroller component. Find more at

For now you can temporarily achieve the hide using [hidden] attribute.
<div class="card flex justify-center">
  <p-virtualscroller
    [items]="items"
    [itemSize]="50"
    scrollHeight="200px"
    styleClass="border border-surface"
    [style]="{ width: '200px', height: '200px' }"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item let-options="options">
      <div
        class="flex items-center p-2"
        [ngClass]="{ 'bg-surface-100 dark:bg-surface-700': options.odd }"
        style="height: 50px"
      >
        <span [hidden]="!item.truthy"> {{ item.label }} </span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-virtualscroller>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo
